# excecute function upon document insertion

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I'm trying to find a way to achieve the following pseudo function on the server.The fields `likesRecieved`  `likesShown`  and `likesMatch` in exist in a document within the Posts collection.

I require this function to perform for **every document in post collection** by default. This is because Id like the function to do this...

**1)** find value(s) that exist in likesRecieved and likedShown fields.

**2)** insert these value(s) in likesMatch field.

**3)** remove values found in operation 1 from likesRecieved and likesShown

**This is what I am essentially trying to do on the server...**

```
 likesRecieved: idA, idB, idE, idF, idL
 likesShown: idE, idC, idF

..perform a function to result in the following...

 likesRecieved: idA, idB, idL
 likesShown: idC,
 likesMatch: idE, idF
```

This is my code to find the ids in both arrays for one document only. The likeMatch helper returns the userIds that may exist in both '`likesRecieved`' and '`likesShown`' fields within a selected document in Posts collection. The resulting value(s) are then inserting into the likesMatch field.

```
   likeMatch: function() {
    var selectedPostId = Session.get('postId'); // _id of document in Post collection

         var arrayOfLikeRecieved = Posts.find({_id: selectedPostId}, {fields: {LikesRecieved: 1}}).fetch();
         var sumArrayRecieved = _.chain(arrayOfLikeRecieved).pluck('LikesRecieved').flatten().value();

         var arrayOfLikeShown = Posts.find({_id: selectedPostId}, {fields: {LikesShown: 1}}).fetch();
         var sumArrayShown = _.chain(arrayOfLikeShown).pluck('LikesShown').flatten().value();

    var duplicates = _.intersection(sumArrayRecieved, sumArrayShown);
    Meteor.call('insertDuplicateIntoMatchField', duplicates);

},
```

Comment: So did you ever think about writing some native code for MongoDB on the server? Cute underscore/lodash stuff but servers do it better. "Unlearn what you have learned" - Wise Jedi Master

Comment: This is what I'm thinking. As I don't know where to start, it is why I posed the question here.  So a link to a relevant document will be very helpful to get me going. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB doesn't have hooks like some other databases do, so there's no way to *automatically* have a function called when a document is inserted.

You have a couple of options, though. One way would be to have a hook in your application that runs just before inserting the document to run your function. This could be achieved in meteor by using a [Collection.deny function](https://docs.meteor.com/#/basic/Mongo-Collection-deny).

If you would prefer to have the function be executed in mongodb, then you'll have to call the function manually. The problem is just how to know when the document was inserted or updated. Luckily, meteor allows you to [observe changes](https://www.eventedmind.com/feed/meteor-observing-cursors) to a cursor. You could use that to make a call out to the database and run a stored procedure (function) whenever a document gets updated.

Comment: This explanation is helpful. I think observe changes would be the best option as I'd only require the function to execute upon an insertion.

 I'm going to modify how how the likesMatch field gets populated with the addition of deny rules. Thanks allTwentyQuestions